# How can I install APK file on Bluestacks app player?

Tags: apk, bluestacks

I have created an Android application using Eclipse, and now I'd like to install the APK on Bluestacks which is running on Windows 7. How can I install an APK on the Bluestacks player?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/24361761#24361761

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just copied my APK file into the `Apps` folder, which is created by default in the `Libraries` folder at the time of BlueStacks installation. Then I just double clicked on the APK file to install it to the App Player. Now I can see the application icon on the home screen of the App Player and I am able to run it from there.

[image]

Answer (score 32):

Save as `app name.apk` and right click on that file and open with `HD-apk handler.exe` which is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks`.

Comment: I logged in just to upvote you. Good and simple solution.

Comment: The correct name is `HD-ApkHandler.exe`. Also Bluestacks installs to `C:\Program Files` on 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 6):

To install an app from your pc, just double click on its apk file; it doesn't matter in which folder it is.

Comment: Wow... this should be the answer. Worked immediately.

Answer (score -1):

its quite simple......
you need BlueStacks app player for this
just download the .apk file of whichever app you wish to  install.
and then open the downloaded .apk file with ""APK handler"" of BlueStacks(the .exe file of the apk handler is present in the root directory of BlueStacks)