# Install APK on Bluestacks for Mac

Tags: apk, macos, bluestacks

How do you install `.apk` file on Bluestacks for Mac? More specifically, where is the directory for Bluestacks kept and do I have the 'APK Handler'?

Comment: For Windows, but might give you an idea: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42983/how-can-i-install-apk-file-on-bluestacks-app-player

Comment: @geffchang nope not really, i clicked through to this question from that because none of the directories it mentioned seemed to exist on my Mac

Comment: @user50338 Have you tried drag-and-drop the apk file onto the bluestacks app player after opening it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this worked well:

> 1. Place the .apk in the `/Runtime` folder:
>
>    ```
>    Macintosh HD/Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/Runtime/filename.apk
>    ```
>
>    (Don't ask why, it was just the only spot that seemed to actually work.
> 2. Open up the terminal. Type:
>
>    ```
>    /Applications/Bluestacks.app/Contents/Runtime/uHD-Adb devices
>    ```
>
>    If there is one device listed, perfect.
>
>    - If not, type this into the terminal:
>
>      ```
>      /Applications/Bluestacks.app/Contents/Runtime/uHD-Adb disconnect
>      ```
> 3. Now once you have a single device listed, type into terminal:
>
>    ```
>    /Applications/Bluestacks.app/Contents/Runtime/uHD-Adb install /Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/Runtime/filename.apk
>    ```

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140421164244/https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/manual_method_to_install_apk_files_on_bluestacks_mac_version)

Comment: This worked for me except in step 1 the path was `/Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/MacOS/filename.apk` and in 2 the command was `/Applications/Bluestacks.app/Contents/MacOS/adb devices` and in 3 the command was `/Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/MacOS/adb install /Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/MacOS/filename.apk`. Possibly due to newer version of BlueStacks.

Comment: @LironYahdav This was a huge help. Worked great to install local file. Confirmed working on High Sierra.

Comment: Indeed, these paths are compatible with the latest Bluestacks version, though I get an error when running the last command (install): `Performing Streamed Install
adb: connect error for write: closed`.

Answer (score 5):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22001499/1793718),

> Open terminal and run the following command:
>
> ```
>  /Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/MacOS/adb install ABSOLUTE_PATH_AND_APK_FILENAME
> ```

**Other Method:** This one is not a solution, but a quick workaround is to have the apk in any cloud storage like Dropbox, Drive, OneDrive etc and download it in your bluestack's Dropbox app and install it. As quoted from [this apple discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4945337),

> The quick and easy method is to :
>
> 1. install dropbox in your bluestacks.
> 2. drop your apk file into your dropbox from mac/pc/phone.
> 3. access your apk file from your dropbox in bluesstacks and install.